# How can you call a URL without opening a browser in C/Side?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

We are using C/Side on one server to try to call a URL to a PHP script on another server without opening a browser window. We want the script to run as a background process. So far, everything we've tried opens a browser. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the code of what you tried to your question

Comment: So you want to call it like a web service? What type of result will be returned by PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I used HttpClient to do this. But it's not that straight forward in Nav, since you cannot call an asynchronous method and assign its return value to a variable. So I created a wrapper class in c#.

```
public class NavHttpClient
{
    private HttpResponseMessage responseMsg;
    public HttpResponseMessage ResponseMsg
    {
        get { return responseMsg; }
    }

    public async Task GetAsync(string requestUri)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        responseMsg = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
    }
}
```

Then I exported this class in a class library. Now I can use it Nav this way:

NavWebClient : DotNet NavWebClient.NavHttpClient.'NavWebClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

```
NavWebClient := NavWebClient.NavHttpClient;
NavWebClient.GetAsync('http://localhost').Wait;

IF NavWebClient.ResponseMsg.IsSuccessStatusCode THEN
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://vjeko.com/blog/web-services-black-belt-consuming-nav-web-services-using-pure-cal) solution suits your needs? Inside there is [link](http://www.mibuso.com/dlinfo.asp?FileID=1472) to codeunit for Nav 2013 that allows to work with web services in Nav style.